# What are the details of this step in a proof of the Banach-Tarski paradox?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, rotations, paradoxes

In [this exposition of the Banach-Tarski paradox by Terry Tao](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/Expository/banach-tarski.pdf), Corollary 1.4 says,

> There exists a partition $S^2 = \Gamma_1 \uplus \dots \uplus \Gamma_8$ and rotation matrices $R_1, \dots, R_8 \in SO(3)$ such that $S^2 = \biguplus_{i = 1}^4 R_i \Gamma_i = \biguplus_{i = 5}^8 R_i \Gamma_i$.

The proof of Corollary 1.4 is omitted; it is indicated that Corollary 1.4 is proven by simply combining two previous results (Lemma 1.3 and Corollary 1.2). I don't understand how Corollary 1.4 follows from Lemma 1.3 and Corollary 1.2.

Concretely, how are $\Gamma_1, \dots, \Gamma_8$ constructed from $\Omega_1, \Omega_2, \Omega_3, \Omega_4, \Sigma_1, \Sigma_2, R, A, B$, etc.?

Comment: A video reference https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=s86-Z-CbaHA

Comment: I think it will involve taking intersections, e.g., $\Gamma_1 = \Sigma_1 \cap \Omega_1$ and $\Gamma_2 = \Sigma_2 \cap \Omega_1$, etc.